# Embedded Resources vs database performance

Tags: c#, performance, embedded-resource, globalization, resx

I am working on the internationalisation of an asp mvc application, the standard is to go through "embedded resources" where from a names, one can have easily a value. Now I have the following constraints:

1. from a KEY-NAME I must have a VALUE (the embedded resource (resx) do good)
2. from a VALUE I must have associated the KEY-NAME: Solution exists but it affects performance in my opinion. The file is not done for such use. No?
3. actually, for a given KEY-NAME, I have more than one single VALUE
   but at least 4: I can put a JSON string or other stuff but I think
   olso that it will affect performance, and it I think "resx" was not
   made for that use like that.

Since I am interested only about performance, should I stay with "embedded resources", or can I use a table in the database, with two indexes on the two columns used for selections. 
Is there any cache management done with the "embedded resources" that I have to re-implemented if I will choose to use data base.

briefly, **I have no clear idea concerning the performance difference between the use of resx file or database table.**
Why everybody is using resx files for internationalisation ? Why not tables in databases ? (our single interest concerne **performance**)

THINKS !

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to matters of performance, there is one golden rule - try it and see. You can never predict in advance what is going to perform better, especially in a case like this, where the differences may be so small that it's hard to tell.

The best thing you can do is to set up some code that uses the two methods and test it under realistic conditions. That's the only reliable way to tell.

My gut feeling would be that resx files are faster, as database access has its overheads, whereas plain file access is very fast, but as I said, the only real way to tell what's best for your case is to try it.

Hope that helps.